# JS put GPS coordinate on a custom JPG/vector

Tags: javascript, gps

I need for a new project to put gps coordonate marker on a custom jpg

i will capture gps coordinate of a soccer player each seconde during a match, with a custom wearable IOT.

so i will have a big Json with gps coordinate.

i'm able to show all coordinate on a gmap map using different js library (gmap.js etc..)

but the challenge here is to put those marker on a Jpg image (the soccer field.jpg)

i can't find a way to do that,
maybe a way to put GPS coordinates marker  on each corner of the field in the image.

Answer (score 0):

Are you not best to convert the lat and long to a distance in meters offset from a known point on the pitch, and then scale the distances according to the size of the image?

If you have a known point on the pitch then the rest of the calculations should be pretty straight forward.